# How to remove a line and paste it at the beginning of a range

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement

How to remove a line and paste it at the beginning of a range?

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
xxxxxxxx
```

For example, here I want to remove the 5th line and paste it before the first two lines, to change the buffer into this:

```
xxxxxxxxline 1
xxxxxxxxline 2
line 3
line 4
```

How to do that with a simple vim command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of alternative methods. They're
both a few more keystrokes than [@statox's
answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16069/343),
but I think they're worth posting because they
show a few different techniques.

### Visual block mode & `Ctrl-R`

Like @statox, I'm presuming you start (on the
first character) of the 5th line for this
solution:

First we yank all the `x` characters (but not the newline):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

Then we delete the line:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Then we jump to the top of the file:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

Then we enter visual block mode, and move down a line so the beginning of the start of both lines are selected:

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>

Then we insert at the start of the visual block. When doing this, anything we insert will be inserted on both lines of the block.

<kbd>`I`</kbd>

Next, we enter the contents of the yank register by using insert mode's Ctrl-R feature. (See [:help i_CTRL-R](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R)):

<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd>

Finally, we leave insert mode:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>

So the complete set of commands is as follows:

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

### Ex Commands

Here's a method that only uses the command line. The following commands can be run with the cursor at any position.

First we move line 5 to the top of the file:

```
:5m0
```

Then we create another copy of that line:

```
:1t2
```

Then we join the lines up:

```
:1,2norm!Jx
```

So, the complete set of ex commands is:

```
:5m0
:1t2
:1,2norm!Jx
```

Comment: Instead of yanking, deleting and then using `<C-r>0` you could also just delete the lines and use `<C-r>"` that still shows the usage of `<C-r>` and save a few keystrokes.

Comment: @statox but then you have to deal with the newline characters. I’m specifically only yanking the line contents to avoid that.

Comment: Of course you are totally right! It was not the smartest comment I've made on this site :)

Comment: @statox Haha we've all done it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following, starting with your buffer like this and your cursor on the first `x` of the last line:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
xxxxxxxx
```

First we copy the last line with <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Your cursor is now on the first `x` of the new last line, so you enter visual bloc mode with <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> and select the lines with <kbd>$</kbd> (to go to the end of the line) and <kbd>k</kbd> to select the line above.

You can then delete the lines with <kbd>d</kbd>

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

You can then use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to go to the first character of the first line and paste what you just deleted with <kbd>P</kbd>

```
xxxxxxxxline 1
xxxxxxxxline 2
line 3
line 4
```

So all in one you can do:

<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

See [`:h visual-block`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#visual-block) for more details about visual block mode.